# using empty on inaccessible object with __isset and __get

Tags: php, getter, magic-methods

```
<?php

class Magic_Methods
{
    protected $meta;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->meta = (object) array(
            'test' => 1
        );
    }

    public function __isset($name) 
    {
        echo "pass isset {$name} \n";

        return isset($this->$name);
    }

    public function __get($name) 
    {
        echo "pass get {$name} \n";

        return $this->$name;
    }
}

$mm = new Magic_Methods();

$meta = empty($mm->meta->notExisting);

var_dump($meta);

echo "||\n";

$meta = empty($mm->meta);

var_dump($meta);
```

The snippet above does not work as expected for me. Why would the first empty() ommit the __isset? I get this:

```
pass get meta 
bool(true)
||
pass isset meta 
pass get meta 
bool(false)
```

I would expected identical results or another pass at the `__isset`, but not a direct call to `__get`. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first call to empty, it is trying to "get" meta so it can test if "notExisting" is empty inside of meta. $meta is just a generic std class with no magic methods so you are not going to get any output (it doesn't call Magic_Methods::__get as $meta isn't an instance of Magic_Methods).

On the second call to empty, it checks to see if meta is set, which it is and so isset returns true. As claudrian says, empty depends on the value so it then tries to "get" meta next so it can determine if the value is empty. It is not empty and so empty returns false. If you change the second call to empty, to isset, it only calls isset which returns true.

Comment: I see, but strikes to me as odd: does empty assume $meta inside Magic_Methods is set because I ask a property? And it drops this assumption when $meta is requested directly. Is this by design, a bug or am I not thinking straight? empty() cannot know the state of $meta...

Comment: @David In the first call, you are not checking empty on meta. You are getting meta and checking empty on `notExisting`. If you call empty on a variable like `$test->foo->bar->blah` would you expect it to call empty on each and every property accessed, "foo", "bar" and "blah"? You are only calling one function, from left to right you would be getting "foo" from "$test" ($test->foo), then getting "bar" from "foo" (foo->bar), then getting "blah" from "bar" (bar->blah) and lastly checking if "blah" isset/empty. the return value from $test->foo->bar->blah is the value passed/checked in empty.

Comment: Ah ha! So it checks from right to left? Now, that makes a lot of sense why it now skips the __isset alltogether.

Answer (score 2):

Read here http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

- **isset**() only cares about existence and not null-ness
- **empty**() takes data type into consideration and, in order to take data into consideration, it needs the value